# Make ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

I am trying to make the following Class parcelable. Usually, I do this by using the parcelabler website. But the website seems to have problems with the ArrayList> part. Does anybody know how to do it properly?
Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.stoos.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class DataModelDiagrammDaten implements Parcelable {
ArrayList<String> Antworten = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> AntwortIDs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

public ArrayList<String> getAntworten() {
    return Antworten;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getAntwortIDs() {
    return AntwortIDs;
}

public void setAntworten(ArrayList<String> antworten) {
    Antworten = antworten;
}

public void setAntwortIDs(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> antwortIDs) {
    AntwortIDs = antwortIDs;
}

public DataModelDiagrammDaten(ArrayList<String> antworten,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> antwortIDs) {
    super();
    Antworten = antworten;
    AntwortIDs = antwortIDs;
}



protected DataModelDiagrammDaten(Parcel in) {
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        Antworten = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(Antworten, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        Antworten = null;
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if (Antworten == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(Antworten);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<DataModelDiagrammDaten> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DataModelDiagrammDaten>() {
    @Override
    public DataModelDiagrammDaten createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DataModelDiagrammDaten(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DataModelDiagrammDaten[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DataModelDiagrammDaten[size];
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a little late, but hope it's still useful for others.
I tried to write a two dimensional Array to Parcel like this:

```
public class Avatar implements Parcelable {

ArrayList<Integer> arrayList;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLists;

public Avatar() {
    arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            temp.add(j);
        }
        arrayLists.add(temp);
    }

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 100; i < 104; i++) {
        arrayList.add(i);
    }
}

protected Avatar(Parcel in) {
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    in.readList(arrayList, Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
    in.readList(arrayLists, ArrayList.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<Avatar> CREATOR = new Creator<Avatar>() {
    @Override
    public Avatar createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Avatar(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Avatar[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Avatar[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(arrayList);
    dest.writeList(arrayLists);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(arrayList.get(i) + " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLists.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayLists.get(i).size(); j++) {
            stringBuilder.append(arrayLists.get(i).get(j) + " ");
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
}
```

And send the class to another Activity:

```
   avatar = new Avatar();
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClass(ParcelActivity.this, Parcel2Activity.class);
   intent.putExtra("avatar", avatar);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Receive in another Activity:

```
textView.setText(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("avatar") + "");
```

It works correctly:
[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RQBS.png)

What should be careful is that writing and reading for the field objects in Parcel must be in the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Try to put the second ArrayList in another class like this:

```
public class IdsObject implements Parcelable {

ArrayList<Integer> ids;

public IdsObject(ArrayList<Integer> ids) {
this.ids = ids;
}


protected IdsObject(Parcel in) {
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        in.readList(ids, Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        ids = null;
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if (ids == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(ids);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<IdsObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<IdsObject>() {
    @Override
    public IdsObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new IdsObject(in);
    }

    @Override
    public IdsObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new IdsObject[size];
    }
};
}
```

Then, use this class on your class like this:

```
public class DataModelDiagrammDaten implements Parcelable, Parcelable {
ArrayList<String> Antworten = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<IdsObject> AntwortIDs = new ArrayList<IdsObject>();


protected DataModelDiagrammDaten(Parcel in) {
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        Antworten = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(Antworten, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        Antworten = null;
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        AntwortIDs = new ArrayList<IdsObject>();
        in.readList(AntwortIDs, IdsObject.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        AntwortIDs = null;
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if (Antworten == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(Antworten);
    }
    if (AntwortIDs == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(AntwortIDs);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<DataModelDiagrammDaten> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DataModelDiagrammDaten>() {
    @Override
    public DataModelDiagrammDaten createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DataModelDiagrammDaten(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DataModelDiagrammDaten[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DataModelDiagrammDaten[size];
    }
};
}
```

Comment: This is the same side I used, but it says 
"The following variables were not recognized (syntax error?):

    ArrayList> AntwortIDs" (in the red Box on the beginning of the side)

Comment: Can you change that variable to a ArrayList<Integer[]> AntwortIDs = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(); ?

Comment: no, unfortunately not, the length of the array ist undetermined

Comment: Try this: - Create a class called IdsObject and put the ArrayList<Integer> in there. - Then, create the respective parcelable with the website i gave you. - After that, just substitute the ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> AntwortIDs with ArrayList<IdsObject> AntwortIDs .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. Here is the solution in case anybody else faces the same problem:
You can first make your class with an normal ArrayList (instead of ArrayList> ) parcelable with the website. Then take the following snippet an write it into the Constructor with the Parcel argument at the place, were the ArrayList was. Now change your ArrayList back to your ArrayList> and it should work.

```
if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        IDs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        Type collectionType =  new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>(){}.getType();  
        in.readList(IDs, collectionType.getClass().getClassLoader());
    } else {
        IDs = null;
    }
```

Comment: My solution solves it too and I think is more appropriate for what you want.